Manifest validation failed: Apps created after the cut off date are not allowed to deploy with the sandbox runtime
I was testing and trying to learn Jira JQL function module. From the examples apps that are listed on the Jira documentation, firstly, I've cloned the project to my laptop. And then I've registered and logged in. Then, I tried to deploy with "forge deploy".
However this error occurs.

"Error: Manifest validation failed: Apps created after the cut off date are not allowed to deploy with the sandbox runtime"

This is my manifest.yml.
modules:
  jira:jqlFunction:
    - key: subtaskOf
      name: subtaskOf
      arguments:
        - name: text
          required: true
      types:
        - issue
      operators:
        - "in"
        - "not in"
      function: subtaskOfFunction
  trigger:
    - key: onIssueCreatedTrigger
      function: onIssueCreatedFunction
      events:
        - avi:jira:created:issue
    - key: onIssueUpdatedTrigger
      function: onIssueUpdatedFunction
      events:
        - avi:jira:updated:issue
  scheduledTrigger:
    - key: periodicalRefreshTrigger
      function: periodicalRefreshFun
      interval: hour
  consumer:
    - key: queue-consumer
      queue: update-precomputations
      resolver:
        function: consumer-function
        method: event-listener
  function:
    - key: subtaskOfFunction
      handler: function.subtaskOf
    - key: onIssueUpdatedFunction
      handler: trigger.onIssueUpdated
    - key: periodicalRefreshFun
      handler: trigger.periodicalRefresh
    - key: onIssueCreatedFunction
      handler: trigger.onIssueCreated
    - key: consumer-function
      handler: asyncEvent.handler
app:
  id: ari:cloud:ecosystem::app/03058011-a9df-4a20-bc49-15984bc201ee
  runtime:
    name: sandbox
permissions:
  scopes:
    - storage:app
    - read:jira-work
    - read:jira-user


The original link to the this example app is here .
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/forge-jql-function-subtaskof/src/master/
Can I know how can I release this bug please?
